# How to get fix these poles which are pinching my the mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have made a rounded mesh using loop tools. But the poles are causing a bad shade when I add the subdivision modifier. Is there a way to improve the mesh?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to make sure that the poles are not on a curved surface or pinching will be quite visible. So make sure that the circular shape is made of loops and that the poles are on the outside of it

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alex, much appreciated for the example.